# How to Delete Text in Word Using Active X Controls

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex

I am currently attempting to create an automated letter on word and know essentially nothing about activex or vba.

I want to create a checkbox that will show text (a subsection of text) only if it is selected. I had originally used a code like this to hide or show text.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TextToHide").Range.Font.Hidden = False
Else
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TextToHide").Range.Font.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

However, since my letter had numbered bullets, depending on which checkbox was selected the order of the letter is completely messed up.
Example: I do not want subsections 1,3,5,6 included in the letter (and it is not) but the bullet's order look like this

2. Subsection...
3. Subsection...
4. Subsection...

I figured the only way to get around this is to completely delete the subsection so that the Bullet numbers are in the correct order. I attempted to write the following code but it will not delete the subsection/bookmarked text.

```
Sub DeleteBookmark()
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TextToHide").Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Could anyone please help me delete the bookmarked text or update the bullet's numbers when hiding a subsection of the letter?

Comment: Note that Active X controls will not function on a Mac. Instead put it in a regular module and use a MacroButton field.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `Delete` method of the `Range` class instead:

```
Sub DeleteBookmark()
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TextToHide").Range.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```